# Top bar tooltip not localized for not logged in user

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, tooltips, localization

Tooltip texts for inbox/achievements buttons are not translated for non-English sites if user is not logged in.

Before log in:

> [image: before]

After log in:

> [image: after]

Tested for:

- Stack Overflow на русском
- Stack Overflow em Português
- Stack Overflow en español

As I can see for *Stack Overflow на русском* mentioned strings are already translated in Transifex database, but only used when user is logged in.

Comment: Works fine for me though

Comment: @PythonMaster did you try private mode in browser?

Comment: Okay never mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These strings were hard-coded, the existing translations were not being used. Fixed.